# How to get list of all JARs dependent by a Gradle app project?

Tags: scala, gradle, jar, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Given a Java or Scala application built using Gradle and dependencies defined by Gradle, is it possible to create a task that simply  generates a list of all JARs (with versions in file name) that are dependent by the app and required to run the application?

Answer (score 2):

add 'project-report' plugin will add tasks for dependency report generation html/txt

https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/project_report_plugin.html